# Convert a str typed series to numeric where I can

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the str type series `s`

```
s = pd.Series(['a', '1'])
```

---

```
pd.to_numeric(s, 'ignore')

0    a
1    1
dtype: object
```

---

```
pd.to_numeric(s, 'ignore').apply(type)

0    <type 'str'>
1    <type 'str'>
dtype: object
```

Clearly, both types are still string.  It seems that the `'ignore'` option ignores the entires series conversion.  How do I get it to do what it can and ignore the rest.

I want the series types to be

```
pd.to_numeric(s, 'ignore').apply(type)

0    <type 'str'>
1    <type 'int'>
dtype: object
```

---

EDIT: I came up with this after I posted the question and after @ayhan provided an answer.

***My solution***
Not vectorized, but gives me exactly what I want

```
s.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

Comment: i don't understand your question. Either you do something like `pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')` and have NaN's but one common dtype `float64` or you will have `object` dtype. You can't have mixed dtypes within one series, AFAIK

Comment: @MaxU I'm not concerned with the `dtype` of the series.  I want the `type` of the individual elements to be numeric where they can be.

Comment: @MaxU the `dtype` object in the latter case will mean that it will be mixed here if the types are not coerced, `Series` support mixed dtypes fine, the `dtype` shown will be `object` but each element will be `str`, `int` in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I am using:

```
pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').fillna(s)
Out: 
0    a
1    1
dtype: object
```

---

```
pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').fillna(s).apply(type)
Out: 
0      <class 'str'>
1    <class 'float'>
dtype: object
```

Comment: @MaxU Yes, the container will be of type object but individual numbers will be treated as numbers. Sometimes you may need those to be evaluated as numbers when applying operations.